# Fixed Background Image while scrolling with Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image

I have an Recyclerview, and I have to put an background image which stays stable while scrolling.

I tried providing background to the parent layout, also tried adding frame layout with the background image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_alpha_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/submenuRv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/submenu_items" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I expected that the image would stay still in the background while scrolling but the image becomes as big as the recycler view height

Answer (score 1):

I Did with `ConstraintLayout` here is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@drawable/full_background"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Change `RecyclerView` property according to your need. above layout is working snipped from my app. I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ImageView` inside the `FrameLayout` as the top child, so it'd work as background and `RecyclerView` as second child, so it'd always be on top of `ImageView`.

Check out the layout below:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/submenuRv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:spanCount="2" />

</FrameLayout>
```

You can then set the `RecyclerView` background to `@android:color/transparent` if it's still showing the white color.

Comment: How does the layout you're recycling in RecyclerView look?

Comment: Its just normal items but I wanted an image to be fixed in background while scrolling the recyclerview

Comment: It will be fixed in background.

Comment: No I goes along with the scroll making the image height larger

Comment: That's not possible. Try removing your nestedScrollingEnabled from RecyclerView. Maybe that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the background of layout using FrameLayout please try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope its work for you.